# Jenkins CI fails to initialise

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I've just installed [Jenkins-CI](http://www.jenkins-ci.org) on Ubuntu 11.10 as according to the instructions found [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu), However the service fails to start. The error log shows this:

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
10 Jun 2012 16:24:06 winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
10 Jun 2012 16:24:10 hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

The entire error log can be found on [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2nJ4iGXm)

I've tried looking for similar errors but I can't find anything. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The instructions work for me. Did you have another implementation of Java installed beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself - `apt-get uninstall openjdk-6-jre openjdk6-jdk` and reinstalling seemed to fix the problem. Not sure why as they were up to date in the first place. Maybe some dependencies were broken.